# How can I populate a tableView having embedded collectionViews in its rows and organize them by type or category?

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, alamofire

I have an event/venue management app & a view receives data for events in json format where each event has a category or type. How do I populate & organize events in collectionViews embedded in TableView cells where each TableView Cell is a category or type to display. **Answers in Swift if possible**

Comment: Do you have `UICollectionViewDataSource` in view controller class or `UITableViewCell` class?

Comment: In the ViewController Class

Answer (score 1):

populate your tableview using JSON with categories and in cellForRowAt method pass single  category to collectionView (your tableview cell class is holding collectionView property) reload collectionView using

```
cell.singleCategory = categories[indexPath.row]
cell.collectionView.reloadData()
```

Place your collectionView outlet and delegate in tableView Cell class and create property that holds single category data pass the  category data to that tableView Cell class and in cellForItemAt populate  single category data

Example:

```
class MyTeamTVC: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
        var singleCategory = [Category]()
override func awakeFromNib() {

        collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "cell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    }
    }

extension MyTeamTVC: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return category.types.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? StatsCVC else {return UICollectionViewCell()}

        cell.nameLabel.text = singleCategory.types[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't clearly understand your answer

Comment: place collectionView in tableView then make xib of collectionViewCell in your main tableViewcell class make collectiobView outlet and then register cell in awake nib 
parse your JSON in main mainViewController where your tableView is placed then populate tableView with categories and pass single category and reload collectionView in cellforRow of tableView.

Answer (score 1):

Create a struct with all available properties and add an enum for categories

```
struct Event {
    enum Category {
        case a
        case b
        case c
    }
    var category: Category
    var eventName: String
    //...
}
```

Create an 2 dimensional array of Event objects

```
var groupedEventsArr = [[Event]]()
```

Once you received the data from the server create an array of Event objects.

```
let eventsArr:[Event] = //json parse
```

Then group the array objects based on `category`

```
groupedEventsArr = Array(Dictionary(grouping: eventsArr, by: { $0.category }).values)
```

Now use this array in tableview, collection view data source methods

//tableview

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return groupedEventsArr.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
    let category = groupedEventsArr[indexPath.row].first?.category
    return cell!
}
```

//collection view

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return groupedEventsArr[section].count
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    let event = groupedEventsArr[indexPath.section][indexPath.item]
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Ok this is practical .. I have a misunderstanding anyways. When I get my data from the server there is **event_category: Sports** field. Does it conflict with the enum ?

Comment: @Carl You need to convert the JSON response to a struct in swift. Check [ex1](https://medium.com/@nimjea/json-parsing-in-swift-2498099b78f), [ex2](https://medium.com/@sdrzn/networking-and-persistence-with-json-in-swift-4-c400ecab402d)